# "Everyone you meet is fighting a battle you know nothing about." in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, sentence-translation

What would be the proper Latin translation of:

> Everyone you meet is fighting a battle you know nothing about.

The [author of the quote is uncertain](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/06/29/be-kind/) and, as far as I can see, it is not a proverb or a common phrase.

Comment: I love that quote, and it took me many years to learn and truly understand its meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase *everyone you meet* seems like a idiomatic way to say *everybody*, so I would translate it as:

> Omnis certamen certat quod nequaquam scis.

A simpler way to say it, although with less emphasis, would be:

> Omnis certamen certat quod nescis.

Answer (score 8):

I'll offer something with a slightly different approach in an attempt to be more idiomatic in structure:

> *Si quis tibi occurrit, sua habet certamina abscondita.*
> If anyone meets you, they have their own hidden struggles.

Opening a sentence with a condition with *si quis* appears to be [very common](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23si+quis%23) and feels like an idiomatic way to say essentially "everyone".

I'm less convinced about my choice *certamina habet*.
Perhaps the verb could be *certat* too?
I wanted to try to give more emphasis to the existence of the fight than the act of fighting so I went with *habere*.
(I don't quite know how to specify that the struggles are hidden from you so [I asked a follow-up question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14777/79).)

If you don't mind dactylic hexameter with some added licence, I could also offer:

> *Quisque tibi occurrens sua semper proelia sumit.*
> Each one that meets you always engages in their own battles.