# Hidden from/by you

Tags: ambiguity, agent

I answered [a question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14773/79) a moment ago and I contemplated phrasing "hidden from you" as *a te absconditum*.
But then I realized that the pronoun could also be taken as an agent, rendering it "hidden by you", which means quite the opposite.
The dative seems to leave the same ambiguity: I can read *tibi absconditum* both ways too.

This leads to an interwoven triplet of questions:

1. Are both readings of *a te absconditum* and *tibi absconditum* valid?
2. How can you say "hidden from you" in Latin so that it cannot be mistaken for "hidden by you"?
3. How can you say "hidden by you" in Latin so that it cannot be mistaken for "hidden from you"?

Insight into any of these three would be most welcome!
If you think they would work best as separate questions, I can split this in three.

Comment: I haven't yet looked this up in a dictionary, but if the verb celare were used instead, I believe that it can take a double accusative in the active (one for things concealed, the other for the person it's concealed from); so in the passive, the accusative of the person could be retained. Of course, that approach could open up other ambiguities, depending on the genders, numbers, and cases of the specific nouns that are involved

Comment: Or actually, perhaps the person would become the subject of the passive, and the thing that's hidden would be the retained accusative? Or maybe both are possible... Will look it up when I have a chance.

Answer (score 4):

If you used cēlō, you could render a phrase like **tē mē cēlō** I hide myself from you. Playing with the order can change emphasis and make it more or less ambiguous, but in theory, it doesn't make sense for a person to hide another from themselves. i.e. I wouldn't hide **you** *from me*

Or you could always use a less literal from of from you, i.e. **absconditus ab oculīs tuīs** "hidden from your eyes/sight" as the Romans often used being in the presence of one's eyes, face, mouth, etc. as being visible or near.

To say "hidden by you" you can use the person and number of a word like cēlō, **mē cēlās** "you hide me"

That being said, ambiguity is part of Latin, you cannot escape it. In the book I'm reworking, there are literally 1000s of sentences where it's kind of a toss up, and I have to ask, is this **fueris** (2nd sg. fut. perf. act. ind.) or **fuerīs** (2nd sg. perf. act. subj.) and there isn't always a way to tell. Context sometimes helps.

Comment: Thanks! Two comments: (1) Before *oculis* it should be *ab(s)*. (2) I can well imagine me hiding you from me. If I know I'm prone to have violent fits (due to intoxication or some other reason), I might want to protect loved ones from it. But of course that would only make sense in rare contexts.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That was my second typo of the day, ugh. Not my day at all.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta actually, realized I had it as ā tuīs occulīs first, then swapped it since adjs. usually follow the noun, but forgot to put ā as ab.